# Connect to local mongodb from Parse Server

Tags: ios, mongodb, localhost, parse-server

I'm trying to connect an iOS app to a local instance of Parse Server.

I've restored a dump of my mongo database using mongorestore and I can connect to it on MongoChef at localhost:27017.

However, connecting to it through Parse Server doesn't seem to be working.
Here's part of my index.js file:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-database-name',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
  fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"]
  }
});
```

Am I setting my databaseURI correctly? I think that's where my problem is.

My local parse server is running on `http://localhost:1337/parse`, and my app is connecting to it with the following code:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = self.applicationId
            $0.clientKey = self.clientKey
            $0.server = self.serverURL
            $0.localDatastoreEnabled = true
        }
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

where serverURL returns `http://localhost:1337/parse`.

But when I run my app with this configuration, my queries return no data.

Comment: Are you running your app in simulator or device?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar In the simulator

Comment: Did you have any success @AdColvin